# Font is serif, should be sans-serif

Tags: html, css, font-family

I created a website in Adobe Dreamweaver. I've set every text to

```
font-family:sans-serif;
```

In the live-view and on the browser (when I just open the html document with the browser locally) everything is sans-serif, just as it should be. However, when the site is online, everything shows as serif text.
I already tried to set it to

```
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
```

but it doesn't work either

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a dreamweaver problem.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I set the CSS to sans-serif, it should be sans-serif, no matter where I wrote the code.

Comment: If you say so :) . .

Comment: Check if your CSS works and can be found when uploaded: add something to this element that should clearly show, such as a glaringly bright green background. If that doesn't appear either, your uploaded page cannot locate the CSS.